# NameError: name 'addition' is not defined

Tags: python

I am getting `NameError: name 'addition' is not defined` while running following code

```
class Arithmetic:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def addition(self):
        c = a + b
        print"%d" %c

    def subtraction(self):
        c=a-b
        print "%d" % c

add = addition(5, 4)
add.addition()
```

Comment: You need to format your question. Try using code blocks and make sure everything is correctly indented and overall looks like your code does. You also need to add a question and what you were expecting the from the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your 'addition' method, you first need to instantiate an Arithmetic() object and use dot notation to call their functions. Make sure you properly indent your code because not only is it breaking a lot of PEP 8 rules but it just looks plain messy. In your first definition, don't forget you have to type **__init__** not **init**. Here's the code which should be applied:

```
class Arithmetic(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def addition(self):
        c = self.a + self.b
        print c

    def subtraction(self):
        c = self.a - self.b
        print c


a = Arithmetic(5, 4)
a.addition()
a.subtraction()
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to create object of class and then you can access class function.
Try this:

```
a = Arithmatic()
a.addition(5,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this piece of code:

```
class Arithmetic():
    def init(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def addition(self):
        c = self.a + self.b
        print"addition %d" %c

    def subtraction(self):
        c = self.a - self.b
        print"substraction %d" %c

obj = Arithmetic()
obj.init(5, 4)
obj.addition()
obj.subtraction()
```